# Imprir tabela listrada usando bootstrap 3 e css3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-3

Tenho um relatório no qual tenho uma tabela com muitas linhas. Mas quando mando imprimir as cores da tabela listrada do bootstrap não aparecem na impressão.

Consigo imprimir as cores nas colunas, como podem ver em:  [jsfiddle.net/pfdiass/1kvmjwxa/2](http://jsfiddle.net/pfdiass/1kvmjwxa/2)

A cor azul foi para exemplificar o que eu consigo fazer até o momento, mas não é o que eu quero. O que quero realmente é imprimir as linhas uma cor branca de fundo e outra na cor vermelho (como no html acima).

Tentei fazer assim, mas não funcionou:

```
@media print {    
    .table.table-striped td:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background-color: red!important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
    }
}
```

Trocando o `<td>` no código acima por `<tr>` o resultado é o que consigo no código postado no jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui! alterei meu código para:

```
@media print {    
  tr:nth-child(even) td{
    background-color: red !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
  }
}
```

Como podem ver aqui:
http://jsfiddle.net/pfdiass/1kvmjwxa/5/